# Setting up an alias in zsh, storing additional information

Tags: linux, mac, bash, zsh, alias

I am trying to build a triplet of aliases in zsh. jc, g1, g2,

`jc  arg1 arg2`

would be the same as the command

`cp -r arg1 arg2`

And `g1` is the same as `cd arg1`

and

`g2` is the same as `cd arg2`

The idea is that I just i entirely forego using cp, and use jc, but then instead of cd'ing into either arg1 or arg2 I can use g1 or g2 to move myself there.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Does `alias` work significantly differently in zsh than it does in bash? Would `alias jc='cp -r'` not work? Or always use -r with cp, with `alias cp='cp -v'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand correctly you want to cp and then cd into the copied directory with one command.

I think the easiest way would be to add the following to your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` file:

```
function cpcd {
    command (cp -R $1 $2) && (cd $1)
}
```

The `&&` ensures that you don't `cd` if the `cp` was unsuccessful.
Th `$1` and `$2` are the arguments that were passed to the command `cpcd`.

Keep in mind this is going to have undefined behavior for when you copy things that aren't directories.

Comment: The ```$k``` indicates the k^th argument here? if I wanted to generalize cp to have optional -R, how would i go about doing that?

Comment: Yes, the `$k` is the `k^th` arg. If you wanted to run it without the -R, then you wouldn't use this function at all, because the cd would fail. It only makes sense to use this if there is a directory, and if there is, then you have to use the -R. This function is fully constrained.